# MySQL: Get rows with different arguments

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets suppose i have the next tables

```
Table names
id | name
1  | mike
2  | john
3  | jack

Table attributes
name_id | skill
1 | css
1 | html
1 | php
2 | html
2 | java
2 | css
3 | java
```

I need to get all id and names that have, for example, css and html attributes. I've tried using "JOIN" but the number of attributes to search for may be different.

I did not tried anything else yet because i can't figure out what to try.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY ...` and `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`:

```
SELECT name_id
FROM attributes
WHERE skill IN ('css', 'html')
GROUP BY name_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skill) = 2
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ecc7/1)

You can join to also get the names.

Comment: Thanks. I've voted for both answer but i am choosing this because of the fiddle example.

Answer (score 3):

```
select names.id, names.name
from
    names
        inner join 
    attributes
        on names.id = attributes.name_id
where skill in ('css','html')
group by names.id, names.name
having count(distinct skill) = 2 -- where 2 is the number of skills you are looking for
```